# ms excel copy multiple spread out cells in worksheet to separate sheet in rows for multiple sheets

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with over 100 separate sheets and 
Each sheet is the same form with cells having different data. I need to be able to go through each sheet and copy the cells in the form with data and input it in a 
Select sheet of rolls. Each roll would represent the data 
From one sheet.

Basicly.  Say for example.  The form on each of the 100
Worksheets was an address book with the typical data for a simple address book. And each worksheet was exactly the same.  How would be able to cycle through each of the 100 sheets and copy the information in the 
Cells into one sheet with each row have the data from
The worksheets sepeatery.  This way I could transfer the
Info into a database.

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro to do this:

```
Public Sub CopyToOneSheet()

    Dim DestSht As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set DestSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DestinationSheetName") 'Change to your sheet name where everything will be copied.

    'Add a header to your distination sheet
    DestSht.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Everything will be copied here."

    'Loop through each sheet.
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Not going to copy the destination sheet.
        If sht.Name <> DestSht.Name Then
            'Copy used range to first available row on destination sheet.
            sht.Range("A2:Z" & sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=DestSht.Range("A" & DestSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next sht

    Set DestSht = Nothing
    Set sht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Alpha frog. From Mr excel forum.          Gave this method.                                         Sub Consolidate_Data()
    Dim i As Long
    Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Name", "Street", "City", "State")   'Headers
    'Copy values from each sheet
    For i = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets(i).Range("E4").Value    'Name
        Sheets(1).Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets(i).Range("E6").Value    'Steet
        Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets(i).Range("H4").Value    'City
        Sheets(1).Range("D" & i).Value

Comment: It would be helpful to post that as a new answer with a link to the Mr Excel thread, and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/783024-copy-free-form-data-multiple-sheets-into-seperate-rows-one-sheet.html#post3832416